# Insert default into not null column if value is null

Tags: mysql

I have a table `foo`, which has a `NOT NULL` column with a default called `message`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    message varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Hello'
)
```

There is a stored procedure `bar` that inserts into `foo`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bar(
    i_id int,
    i_message varchar(64)
)
BEGIN

    -- other logic

    IF i_message IS NOT NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO foo (id, message) VALUES (i_id, i_message);
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO foo (id, message) VALUES (i_id, DEFAULT);
        -- could also be: INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (i_id);
    END IF;
 END;
```

You can see, I have to conditionally branch in order for my insert to use the default if `i_message` is null. That's fine for just one column, but consider if `foo` had many more `NOT NULL DEFAULT` columns - the syntax would be way to unwieldy.

Is there a syntax I can use to specify that an inserted value should fall back to the default if null? I tried the following but understandably got syntax errors:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, message) VALUES (i_id, COALESCE(i_message, DEFAULT));
INSERT INTO foo (id, message) VALUES (i_id, IFNULL(i_message, DEFAULT));
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
  INSERT INTO foo (id, message) 
  VALUES
  (i_id, IFNULL(i_message,DEFAULT(message)));
```

Comment: How is this possible in MSSQL server ?

Comment: @user1844205: beats me, never use MSSQL, search MSSQL's docs, or ask the question here on SO.