# Upon insert, how can I programmatically convert a null value to the column's default value?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in for which I have provided default values for some of its columns. I want to create a function with arguments corresponding to the columns that will insert a record in the table after modifying any null value to the column's default value.I dont want to programmatically construct the query based on which arguments are null. Essentially I would like something like

```
INSERT into Table (c1, c2, c3, c4)
Values (coalesce(somevar, DEFAULT(c1)), ...)
```

Is this possible? I ve seen that [mysql can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867593/insert-default-into-not-null-column-if-value-is-null). Does postgres offer anything similar?
I am using version 9.1

UPDATE: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres) provides some interesting solution but unfortunately the results are always text. I would like to get the default value as its true datatype so that I can use it for inserting it. I have tried to find a solution that will cast the default value  from text to its datatype (which is provided as text) but I can't find a way:

```
SELECT column_name, column_default, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('public', 'mytable')
AND column_name = 'mycolumn'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

The above returns the column_default and data_type as text so how can I cast the column_default to the **value** of data_type? If I could do this, then my problem would be solved.

Comment: Can you explain? My columns are declared as NOT NULL DEFAULT xxx

Comment: Also the keyword DEFAULT cannot be used inside a CASE or coalesce. It throws an error: insert into table (c1, c2) values (some_var, coalesce(some_other_var, DEFAULT)) --> throws a syntax error

Comment: Sorry for the noise, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table definition accepts an INSERT with the default values for all columns, the two-steps method below may work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_func(c1 typename, c2 typename, ...)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
 r record;
BEGIN
 INSERT into the_table default values  returning *,ctid INTO r;
 UPDATE the_table set
  col1=coalesce(c1,r.col1),
  col2=coalesce(c2,r.col2),
  ...
 WHERE the_table.ctid=r.ctid;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The trick is to get all the default values into the `r` record variable while inserting and use them subsequently in an UPDATE to replace any non-default value. `ctid` is a pseudo-column that designates the internal unique ID of the row that has just been inserted.

**Caveat**: this method won't work if some columns have a default null value AND a non-null check (or any check that implies that the default value is not accepted), since the first INSERT would fail.

Answer (score 0):

I ve worked around my problem with a solution similar to Daniel's by creating a temp table with `LIKE` and `INCLUDING DEFAULTS` clauses in order to match my rowtype, then i use

`INSERT INTO temp_table (c1, c2, ...) VALUES(x1, DEFAULT, ..)`

using the default keyword for whatever column i am interested in. Then I insert to the real table by selecting from the temporary and using

`VALUES( x1, coalesce(x2, temp_table.c2), ...)`.

I dont like it, but it works ok: I can select which on which columns I would like to do this "null-replace-with-default" check and it could work for many rows with one pass if I overload my function to accept a record array.