# PHP MySQL - How to insert default value in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

Let's say I have a prepared statement that looks like this:

```
$insertSql = "";
$insertSql .= "INSERT INTO table";
$insertSql .= "(tag,month_interval,month_interval_lastupdated,date_due,date_due_lastupdated,date_completion,date_completion_lastupdated,";
$insertSql .= "activeNotification,date_lastmodified) ";
$insertSql .= "VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?,NOW(),?,NOW(),?,NOW())";
```

But sometimes some of those question marks would not be set.

Is there a keyword I can substitute in the prepared statement that tells MySQL to insert the default?

Something like:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertSql)) {
   if(!isset($tag)) {
      // code to find first question mark and replace w/ default value
      }
      $stmt->bind_param('sisss',$tag,$month_interval,$date_due,$date_completion);
      $stmt->execute();
}
```

The default value for the date fields is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' and the default value for month_interval is 0, the rest of the fields have a default of NULL.

Comment: I hope you don't think your first code block as a *prepared statement*, as the prepared statement bit is your second code block.  Is it a requirement to produce your sql in 5 parts? Also, what is the default value?

Comment: The default value for the dates is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' and the default value for month_interval is 0, the rest has a default of NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question addresses an interesting subject, in my opinion.

By a rapid search, I don't have found any predefined solution, but I will continue search in the next days.

I have elaborate a solution, but it is a bit twisted and not totally clean.

First of all, I redefine the query with placeholders:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO table
                (
                    tag,
                    month_interval,
                    month_interval_lastupdated,
                    date_due,
                    date_due_lastupdated,
                    date_completion,
                    date_completion_lastupdated,
                    activeNotification,
                    date_lastmodified
                )
         VALUES (<tag>,<month_interval>,NOW(),<date_due>,NOW(),<date_completion>,NOW(),<activeNotification>,NOW())
";
```

In this example, I use `<>` to surround placeholder, but you can choose your preferred placeholder, making sure that they do not confuse with others elements of the query.

Then, I init an associative array with keys as placeholders names and values to be bind, and a variable (`$types`) with the complete set of bind types:

```
$values = array( 'tag'=>$tag, 'month_interval'=>$month_interval, 'date_due'=>$date_due, 'date_completion'=>$date_completion, 'activeNotification'=>$activeNotification );
$types = 'sisss';
```

Then, the most important line. I init an array in this strange way:

```
$bind = array( Null, '' );
```

The index 0 is set to `Null`, because is reserved for the `stmt` object (created below); the index 1 is an empty string that will be filled with necessary bind types.

Now I perform a `foreach` loop through all elements of array `$values`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $values as $key => $val )
{
    if( is_null( $val ) )
    {
        $query = str_replace( '<'.$key.'>', 'DEFAULT', $query );
    }
    else
    {
        $query    = str_replace( '<'.$key.'>', '?', $query );
        $bind[1] .= $types[$i];
        $bind[]   = &$val;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

In that loop, if the value is null I replace the corresponding query's placeholder with mySQL keyword `DEFAULT`. Otherwise, I replace placeholder with a `?`, I add the corresponding `$types` substring to `$bind[1]`, and I append the value (by reference) to `$bind` array.

At this point, the real query is ready to go, and I can prepare it:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( $query ) or die( $stmt->error );
```

and, if there are not default values (`count($bind)>2`), I can bind it:

```
if( count($bind)>2 )
{
    $bind[0] = $stmt;
    call_user_func_array( 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param', $bind );
}
```

As said before, I set `$bind[0]` to stmt object returned by `->prepare`, then I use `call_user_func_array` to perform `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. I can't directly call `->bind_param` because I have a variable arguments number.

At the end of this eccentric process, finally I can execute the query:

```
$stmt->execute() or die( $stmt->error );
```

I have tested this code, and it works.

The main problem reside in the `is_null( $val )`: using an array, I can't use `isset` as test, because every element of an array is even set. The code works if all the field with placeholder that allows Null value has Null ad default value.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, so I adapted this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867665/1251063 to php prepared statement:

```
if(!($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES (IFNULL(?,DEFAULT(myfield)))"))){
    throw new Exception("Prepare failed: (" . $this->conn->errno . ") " . $this->conn->error);
}

if(!($stmt->bind_param("s",$myfield))) { //$myfield is a variable that can be null, if so the default value for such field will be inserted
    throw new Exception("Bind_param failed: (" . $this->conn->errno . ") " . $this->conn->error);
}

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    throw new Exception("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. Let me give this a try and I'll accept if it works. Essentially that `DEFAULT(field)` function is what I was looking for. I think the `IFNULL` part can be done on the php end.

Comment: In fact, I can do `INSERT INTO table SET date=DEFAULT;`

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, if you have a condition when you do not know all the values, you should prepare the statement to do not even add those values.

Also in **some** cases (for example on **autoincrement** fields) you can just insert a `NULL`  which will trigger the default value to be inserted, ***BUT*** do be carefull if the field definition does allow `NULL's` inserting a `NULL` will insert a `NULL`.

Comment: What about the case where the value is something like `2015-01-01 23:32:23` and the user inputs `nothing` to indicate that the value is either `null` or `default`. You still want it to be in the prepared statement

Comment: for me this is even more important because I have scripts running calculations on the dates in the database. If the value ever pops out as `NULL` that is a big big problem.

Comment: I strongly recommend against this for portability reasons, it doesn't work for all versions, my server version is 5.6.37 and it doesn't work